# Writing a scope to display all items that do not equal nil - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am struggling with writing a specific scope and your help would be much appreciated.

In the `event.rb file`, I have managed to write a scope that displays all events that do not have payments. in other words, displays events that users have not paid to attend. Therefore events with payments where the `event_id is nil`

```
scope :unbooked_events, -> { includes(:payments).where(payments: { event_id: nil }) }
```

> could one kindly tell me how i write a scope that displays all events
>   that have payments, therefore events with payments where the `event_id
>   is not nil`. I tried the below but this displays payments with an
>   `event_id = 1` only rather than all payments where the event_id that is not
>   nil.

```
scope :booked_events, -> { includes(:payments).where(payments: { event_id: !nil }) }
```

your advise would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails 4.x, try with `.where.not`, something like:

```
scope :unbooked_events, -> { includes(:payments).where.not(payments: { event_id: nil }) }
```

Take a look at [not-conditions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions)

For Rails 3.x

```
scope :unbooked_events, -> { includes(:payments).where("payments.event_id IS NOT NULL") }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
scope :unbooked_events, -> { includes(:payments).where('payments.event_id is not NULL') }
```

It is easily understandable.